# How to move eclipse control panel to ubuntu top panel?

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, compiz

After playing with compiz tool in ubuntu 12.04 (changed opacity of ubuntu top panel) something gone wrong with my eclipse indigo. It won't display control panel in ubuntu top panel (default place for windows' controls) but takes whole next line under ubuntu panel. All other applications didn't change behavior. Does anyone know how to roll things back?

Comment: I have had similar issues. Actually the top panel of your window has gone behind the ubuntu top panel. Press alt+space to bring up the context menu and you can select maximize or restore from there and the topbar would be restored.
This might not be the exact issue you're having,but you could give it a try.

Comment: Don't understand "behind the ubuntu top panel". It's maximized (alt-space didn't help) but still takes whole new line for controls ("File, Edit, etc")